# CSS make set minimum page height/width

Tags: css

In the page layout I am creating, for some reason, the scrollbars never seem to show and rather the content tries to rearrange itself. Is there a way to lock in a set width and height for the whole page so that if the window is scaled it shows scrollbars?

The page: http://thetalkingcloud.com/clipit.com/

Specifically, if you make the window small, the "COPY PASTE SHARE" links change their position dramatically.

Thanks if anyone can help out :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make layout more "fluid," specifically the slogan in the header, try making the following changes to `.top_text`

```
.top_text {
    float: right;
    font-family: "Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-size: 60px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 24px;
}
```

You will still need to establish a minimum width for the page.  Because IE6 doesn't support the `min-width` property, I often achieve this simply by placing an empty div with the desired minimum width at the top of whatever container I would otherwise use `min-width` on.

Comment: thanks but when the window is resized to very small dimensions, the slogan text still rearranges and slides under the logo.
What I want (if possible?) is a way for scrollbars to appear when the window becomes smaller than a set size

Answer (score 0):

Your top div has a percentage width, instead give it a fixed pixel width so it does not collapse.